# Java Multimap does get method create a dynamic allocation of a temporary list?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Java Multimap does .get() method create a **dynamic allocation of a temporary list?**
From the source code:

```
Collection<V> get(@Nullable K key);


Returns the set of all keys, each appearing once in the returned set.
Changes to the returned set will update the underlying multimap, and vice
versa.

@return the collection of distinct keys
```

Comment: please clairify this question - too brief

Answer (score 2):

`Multimap` is an interface, so ultimately the answer will depend on the implementation.  If we take `ArrayListMultimap` as an example, we can see the source code here:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.java

If you trace up the inheritance hierarchy, you'll find that `get` is defined in abstract base class `AbstractMapBasedMultimap`:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java#303

We can see that if not found, then a `Collection` is created for the key:

```
@Override
public Collection<V> get(@Nullable K key) {
  Collection<V> collection = map.get(key);
  if (collection == null) {
    collection = createCollection(key);
  }
  return wrapCollection(key, collection);
}
```

For the implementation of `createCollection`, we need to go back down to `ArrayListMultimap`:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.java#129

```
@Override List<V> createCollection() {
  return new ArrayList<V>(expectedValuesPerKey);
}
```

Here we can see that a new list is being created on demand.  However, it would be incorrect to call it "temporary" as described in the original question.  This is going to be the real list backing that entry in the map.

However, keep in mind that this answer is for one specific implementation of `Multimap` and one specific version of the codebase.  This demonstrates the process of exploring the code though, so if you have questions about other implementations or other versions, then you can browse through the code to see the behavior.

Comment: This isn't quite right -- it only allocates a new list if there are no values for that key, and it's not, as the OP describes it, "temporary", it's the real thing. (You can easily test this by calling `get()` and adding values to the returned `List`, then looking for those values back in the `Multimap`.)

Comment: (I'm pretty sure none of the implementations allocate a temporary collection as that would go against the contract of providing a live view, but I haven't actually checked them all.)

Comment: @DavidMoles, great clarification.  Thanks for suggesting that!  I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Note, however, that if you call `get(K)` and it returns an empty collection and you do _not_ add anything to that collection, it will be temporary in the sense that the collection that's created will be GCed when you no longer have any references to it. That's because the backing collection (i.e. the `ArrayList` created by `ArrayListMultimap`) is only added to the backing `Map` when it has at least one element.

Comment: Note that `wrapCollection` creates a new object every time